# how to parse rest api array of array in codeigniter and insert into database

Tags: rest, codeigniter, api

In codeigniter how to insert this values to database when the values are in mulitple array

```
 {tat=6, 
    sId=up, 
    muid=2, 
    cId=msVK,
    photo=, 
    Id=564564, 
    questions={34=Yes, 46=good, 48=NA, 29=Yes, 45=ravi, 49=Negative , 43=1 BHK, 35=Neighbour, 38=14, 39=9, 27=1, 
    41=Married, 52=v@mm.com, 47=good, 31=Bunglow, 33=Middle Class, 37=Owned By Parents, 30=good, 50=easy, 
    51=comments, 32=No, 44=[MusicSystem , PC, Refrigerator, Airconditioner]}}
```

Comment: in which format you are getting response?

Comment: json format using rest api i have to save it to table

Comment: above code is not in json fromat.post your json code.

Comment: json format code look like "tat":"6",
"sId":"up" .you need to provide datatype as JSON to output the data like this "tat":"6".

Comment: above code is from android consol